# Pandas GroupBy Filtering

Tags: pandas

I am looking to understand how to filter a groupby object.

I am generating this through:

```
groupby = df.groupby(['Order #', 'ProductLine', 'ProductType']).size()
```

And the result is:

```
Order #     ProductLine     ProductType       QTY
  1              A              Z              1
                                Y              1
                 B              X              2
  2              A              Z              1
                                Y              1
  3              A              Y              1
                 B              X              1
```

I need to filter out two conditions:

1. Orders where only Product A is contained
2. Orders where Product A is contained, but there is no ProductType Z

In the example above, only order 1 is legitimate.  Order 2 and 3 would be filtered out.

Answer (score 3):

`filter` takes a callable that returns a boolean.  That callable will take the entire groups dataframe.  If the boolean is `True`, the dataframe comes back.  If `False` then nothing comes back.

***Only `A`***

```
def f(df):
    v = df.ProductLine.values
    return (v == 'A').all()

df.groupby(['Order #', 'ProductLine', 'ProductType']).filter(f)
```

***`A` and not `Z`***

```
def f(df):
    v = df.ProductLine.values
    return ('A' in v) and ('Z' not in v)

df.groupby(['Order #', 'ProductLine', 'ProductType']).filter(f)
```